# Simple query working for years, then suddenly very slow

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I've had a query that has been running fine for about 2 years.  The database table has about 50 million rows, and is growing slowly.  This last week one of my queries went from returning almost instantly to taking hours to run.

```
Rank.objects.filter(site=Site.objects.get(profile__client=client, profile__is_active=False)).latest('id')
```

I have narrowed the slow query down to the Rank model.  It seems to have something to do with using the latest() method.  If I just ask for a queryset, it returns an empty queryset right away.

```
#count returns 0 and is fast
Rank.objects.filter(site=Site.objects.get(profile__client=client, profile__is_active=False)).count() == 0
Rank.objects.filter(site=Site.objects.get(profile__client=client, profile__is_active=False)) == [] #also very fast
```

Here are the results of running EXPLAIN. http://explain.depesz.com/s/wPh

And EXPLAIN ANALYZE: http://explain.depesz.com/s/ggi

I tried vacuuming the table, no change.  There is already an index on the "site" field (ForeignKey).

Strangely, if I run this same query for another client that already has Rank objects associated with her account, then the query returns very quickly once again.  So it seems that this is only a problem when their are no Rank objects for that client.

Any ideas?

Versions:
Postgres 9.1,
Django 1.4 svn trunk rev 17047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've not shown the actual SQL, so that makes it difficult to be sure. But, the explain output suggests it thinks the quickest way to find a match is by scanning an index on "id" backwards until it finds the client in question.

Since you said it has been fast until recently, this is probably not a silly choice. However, there is always the chance that a particular client's record will be right at the far end of this search.

So - try two things first:

1. Run an analyze on the table in question, see if that gives the planner enough info.
2. If not, increase the stats (ALTER TABLE ... SET STATISTICS) on the columns in question and re-analyze. See if that does it.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/planner-stats.html

If that's still not helping, then consider an index on (client,id), and drop the index on id (if not needed elsewhere). That should give you lightning fast answers.

Comment: Setting up a compound index on the field in the WHERE as well as the field in ORDER BY did the trick.  Turns out the query planner was scanning through the entire index for the sort, and then doing the filter.  The compound index did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

latests is normally used for date comparison, maybe you should try to order by id desc and then limit to one.

Comment: I tried that and there was also a similarly long delay.  When I look at the raw SQL generated by the ORM, both produce equivalent output.